# Mat-datepicker sending current date into my database through API service

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material, angular6

I'm using `mat-datepicker` in my project. I want to send date which user select but the issue is my datepicker is sending current date into my database. I'm sending data into database through API. 
Here is HTML

```
  <input name="RegDate" #RegDate="ngModel" [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="objCompany.RegDate" class="form-control datepicker" required />
     <mat-datepicker-toggle class="datepicker-toggler" [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: Try to print `objCompany.RegDate` in the html

Comment: Yeah it shows me correct date which I selected. But sending current date into database.

Comment: Can you share the code for API call, if `objCompany.RegDate` is used then selected data will be send. Try checking in the backend as well

Comment: `Insert(obj: CompanyModel) {
    console.log('OBJECT : ', obj);
    obj.ID = 0;
    obj.Active =1;
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/SaveCompany", obj);
  }`